# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "dmidecode"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have a python code that it has different packages like "dmidecode". I installed `dmidecode` using `Python Interpreter` successfully. But when I run the code, I receive this error:

> import dmidecode
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dmidecode'

Also, I installed `dmidecode` like this:

```
pip install dmidecode
```

But I received the same error again.

Would you please guide me what is wrong with installing `dmidecode`?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: *I installed dmidecode using Python Interpreter*, did you do ```pip install dmidecode```?

Comment: Dear @Sujay, thank you for your feedback. Yeah, I do that, but I receive the same error.

Comment: What OS are you working with?

Comment: @ductTapeIsMagic, OS is ```Windows 10```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check, whether your python interpreters (from your pycharm project and where you installed your packages) are the same?

Check if your package is in File/Settings/Project:"YourProjectName"/Python Interpreter All installed packages for this interpreter are listed there.
If it is not, you should change your python interpreter for that project

Comment: Do you mean, the packages that I installed must be in the same path of python interpreter?

Comment: No, when you create a new pycharm project normally a new virtual python env is created too. 
But if you installed your package in your default (non-virtual env) than it could be a diffrent one, than your python-env which is used by your pycharm project

Comment: Check if your package is in File/Settings/Project:"YourProjectName"/Python Interpreter All installed packages for this interpreter are listed there.

Comment: If it is not, you should change your python interpreter for that project :)

Comment: Dear @Tim, thank you. I change python interpreter and it solved.